# Omit function parameter in an Eval

Tags: vba, ms-access, eval

Using `Eval("aFunction(,foo)")` will throw an error

`aFunction(,foo)` works

Answer (score 0):

Don't know *aFunction*, but how about:

```
Eval("aFunction(," & foo & ")")
```